# How can I determine the auto-reply status using a vba macro?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a script that runs when an email comes in that requires automated testing to run, but I want it to respond differently if my auto-reply feature is turned on, is there any way of reading the auto-reply status by an Outlook VBA macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean your OOF status? Read the PR_OOF_STATE property (DASL name "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B`") using Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.

EDIT:

```
set Store = Application.Session.DefaultStore
isOof = Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661D000B")
MsgBox isOof
```

Comment: Please could you a sample code of how this property could be read and say outputted to MsgBox